# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission android.googleapis.com:443 connect,resolve)

Tags: android, web-services, google-cloud-messaging

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.net.SocketPermission android.googleapis.com:443 connect,resolve)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1034)
    sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:271)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:328)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:172)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:793)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:158)
    sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:896)
    sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:468)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.post(Sender.java:447)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.sendNoRetry(Sender.java:170)
    com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.send(Sender.java:121)
    com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.doPost(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:91)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:244)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:276)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

i refferd from http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/... so except this solution.. pl help me to resolve this error.. i have given all permissions in manifiest file too..the thing is.. i host my war file on web.. when i run client pgm from android emultor .. the server register the client(i.e. server getting response from client(emulatore) but when i send msg from server to client im getting above error)..also i have used browser api key

Answer (score 2):

Put the Permission in menifest file:

```
      <permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" /> 
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error - I have build serverside .war file and deployed it on free java hosting eatj. It seems like my free host does not have permissions